# Script for Sum of Rows in field calculator - VB or Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

I wrote the `TOTAL_FREQUENCY` values manually. But I want to automatically write this values with a script. Namely, I want to write sum of column 3 to all of the the column 5 rows. How can I do it with a script?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following standalone-script should do the work for ArcGIS 10.x:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'myGeodatabase'

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor('myLayer', ['frequency'])
sum = 0
for row in cursor:
    sum += row[0]

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor('myLayer', ['total_frequency'])
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = sum
    cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor
```

Comment: should I write this script to the field calculator ?

Comment: No, click the Python-window (should be visible next to the Open ArcToolbox-button in ArcMap).

Comment: @HimBromBeere, you are not changing the field between the search and update cursor, thus overwritten the original field values.

Comment: @artwork21 Indeed, you´re right, updated

Comment: I dont understand how to do, can you give more details ? how to use this code in ArcMAP ?

Comment: On your image I can see (in the very first line of tools) the Python-Window next to the ArcrToolbox (the red icon in the middle of the first line). Use this and copy the code there.

Answer (score 1):

The following Python script (created by Terry Giles and mentioned in this [ESRI forum](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1728&t=241385)) allows you to sum the values of a field and paste the sum in another field. The script is designed to work in the **Toolbox** so that when you run it, you can enter the *Layer name, Field name* and *output*:

```
#args to pass in:
  ##1 = input FC or table
  ##2 = field to sum up
  ##3 = field to write sum into

import arcpy, sys

intable = sys.argv[1]
field = sys.argv[2]

# Create search cursor
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(intable)
row = rows.Next()
x = 0.0
# Enter while loop for each feature/row
while row:
    x += row.getvalue(field)
    print x
    row = rows.next()
#note value can be rounded depending on field type
gp.calculatefield(intable,sys.argv[3],float(x),"PYTHON")
```

---

*Disclaimer: I am not an ArcGIS user therefore cannot confirm if this still works as this script was first posted way back in 2007.*

Comment: `arcgisscripting` is replaced by `arcpy`, no need to create a `gp`-instance.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Many thanks buddy! Edited post but if it is still incorrect, I would rather you post the working script as an answer and I will remove mine =)

Comment: No need to remove it, although it is a bit old it works for the toolbox which is other opportunity. Maybe you should reroll your edit and notice that this works for ArcGIS 9.x. In the current way it won´t work at all I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems OP seeking field calculator expression. Here is one:

```
def getTotal(name,field):
 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
 lr=arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd,name)[0]
 tbl=[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(lr,field)]
 return sum(tbl)
```

=======================================

```
getTotal( "frekans","frequency")
```